# React Native Function Call

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am very new to react native and out of curiosity I want to know that whether we can call a function which is defined inside useEffect hook, outside of the hook? Like, everytime i refresh the page the function should be fired. I have thought of this approach, if any better solutions are available kindly guide. I am using a functional component. This is what i want to acheive:

```
RefreshControl component
 {somefunction()}

useEffect(
somefunction(){

//function body
}
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

No, function will not be accessible outside of [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect). Regular Javascript rules apply.

Why would you not define it outside of `useEffect`?

```js
const foo = () => { console.log('yay') };

useEffect(() => {
  foo();
}, [])
```

It is also not rally clear what `everytime i refresh the page` means in the context of `react-native`, could you elaborate?

There is another way to "trigger" `useEffect`, to call it indirectly:

```js
function C {
  [t, setT] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const foo = () => console.log(t);
    foo();
  }, [t])
  return <Button onPress={() => setT(new Date())} title="Trigger foo" />
}
```

Above `useEffect` will be called at least every time `t` changes.

Comment: Haha. No no. Actually you have got me wrong. What i meant is, I will use the RefreshControl component of react native and inside that i will call a function (foo()). The foo is defined inside useEffect hook. So i was asking if it is callable or not

Comment: Sure but then do not define it in `useEffect` hook. Is there any reason to do this? If otherwise you are asking how to manually trigger `useEffect` which calls that function it is another thing. I'll update with a suggestion to make it clearer